# WPF mahapps in a UserControl throws exception Cannot locate resource 'styles/colors.xaml'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, mahapps.metro

Everything works fine if I use the example code in an application but I need to use it in a UserControl and I won't have access to App.Xaml because it's going into someone elses framework:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyAssembly.Views.MyPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Height="90" Width="120" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor "/>
            <TextBlock Text="incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud "/>
            <TextBlock Text="exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure"/>
            <TextBlock Text="dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "/>
            <TextBlock Text="Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The exception the above code throws looks like (not the whole thing but should be enough) :

```
Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,     IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)

******************************************
Cannot locate resource 'styles/colors.xaml'.
at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetContentType(WebResponse response)
at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponseStream(WebRequest request, ContentType& contentType)
at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Source(Uri value)
at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.<Create_BamlProperty_ResourceDictionary_Source>b__1c4(Object target, Object value)
at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the owner of the framework is using an older version of mahapps (0.999) which has colors spelled colours, since theirs is loaded first, mine crashes. Loading the older version only worked for one compile, I'm opting out of using it just for scrollbar "continuity"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your xaml url to ResourceDictionary:

```xaml
 <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../styles/colors.xaml" />
                 (...)
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```